# How to use if-else condition(in downstream job) to check parameter passed from upstream job in jenkins?

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure mail notifications with success/fail status of Jenkins job. I have a separate job for triggering mails.

I need to trigger two different mails for fail and success scenarios. For that I have below code

```
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*

def  d_email = "noreply@kpn.com",
     d_uname = "noreply@kpn.com",
     d_password = "",
     d_host = "safemail.kpnxchange.com",
     d_port  = "25", //465,587
     m_to = "abc@kpn.com",
     m_subject = "Deployment status Jenkins Job: ${params.JobID}#${params.BuildNumber}- ${params.Status}",
     m_text_success = "Success mail"
     m_text_fail = " failure mail "

def props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", d_host)
def session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props)
session.setDebug(true);

try {
    def msg = new MimeMessage(session)

    if (${params.status} == "Success") {
        msg.setText(m_text_success)
    } else {
        msg.setText(m_text_fail)
    }
    msg.setSubject(m_subject)
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email))
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to))
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println('message sent');
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Here in above job `${params.Status}` is the variable which is being passed from upstream job. And I need to check if the value of `${params.Status}` coming to downstream as `Success` then it should set `msg.setText(m_text_success)` and if value of `${params.Status}` coming to downstream as `Fail` it should set `msg.setText(m_text_success)`

I am not able to get if-else condition in working state.

Comment: `${params.status}` must go into a string or rather just use `params.status` directly

Comment: @cfrick Thanks it worked fine for me. Its just that, now for both `success and fail` scenario I am getting `fail` message body. I guess I will check that.

Comment: Then `params.status` is _not_ equal `Success`. What is it?

Comment: I tried switching `if condition` as ```if (${params.status} == "Fail") {
        msg.setText(m_text_fail)
    } else {
        msg.setText(m_text_success)
    }``` And after doing so for both `success/fail` i am getting `success` mail

Comment: seems like while sending mail it is picking last `msg.setText{}` value

Comment: My bad, found the issue. I was using this `${params.status}` instead of `${params.Status}`. Now it is working fine. :)

Comment: Swapping the if branches and hoping for a miracle cure wont help. Instead of cargo culting around the problem: find out what the actual value of `params.status` is and if it's nil, then check what `params` contains.  Log it or println it.

Answer (score 0):

If you `status` is a String, then this should work

```
if (params.status.equalsIgnoreCase('success')) {
```

And a side note, params/parameters are known to be case sensitive, do check if you use exactly the same name.

Comment: Do remember that this is groovy, not java, therefore `params.status == 'success'` is perfectly fine.  Do check whether it's **s**tatus or **S**tatus and also whether `success` should start with upper-case **S**.

Comment: Aleks, but that's exactly what I wrote (about the status). Yeah, `==` would work as well, but it's hard to tell if OP provides matching values (and `==` is case sensitive as well).

Comment: Yep. My comment was  mainly about using `==` as this is groovy.